# Compare a string column from a joined table to an array of optional strings in LINQ / entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

I have a .net 4.6 webAPI where I am trying to pass in an optional parementer which will be an array of strings called locations.

I would like to determin if I passed in this parameter or not and then if I do have an array of locations I would like to determine if a column from a joined table/model is equal to any of the strings in the locations array.

I used an if else to switch between the two queries where I am comparing  to the locations which seems adequate.

**My issue is i do not know how to iterate through all elements in the locations array and compare it to the entire array rather than one element in the line that says 
dealer.Location.Contains(x))**. I can compare it to a single element X but I cannot correctly implement this strategy to compare it all at once to an array of strings rather than a single string outlined in [This post(non accepted answer with the most votes is what I was trying to go for an failed).[this link]] I change my where line to locations.Any(dealers.LocationName.Contains)) The error i get when trying that is

> {"Internal .NET Framework Data Provider error 1025."}

Update: i Thought i may need to throw a AsQueryable after the locations in my where clause  however that doesnt seem to fix it

```
 public IHttpActionResult getAllCars([FromUri] string[] locations=null)
    {
        string y = "foo";
        string x = locations[0] ?? y;
        using (dbContext db = new dbContext())
        {
            if (locations == null)
            {
               var query = (from results in db.Cars
                             join dealers in db.Dealers on results.DealerID equals dealer.DealerNumber
                             select new
                             {
                                 ID = results.VinNumber,
                                 make = results.Make,
                                 model = results.Model,
                                 Dealer = dealers.DealerName
                             });
                return Ok(query.ToList());
            }
            else
            {
                var query = (from results in db.Cars
                             join dealers in db.Dealers on results.DealerID equals dealer.DealerNumber
                            where (dealer.LocationName.Contains(x))
                             select new
                             {
                                 ID = results.VinNumber,
                                 make = results.Make,
                                 model = results.Model,
                                 Dealer = dealers.DealerName
                             });
                return Ok(query.ToList());
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the list of cars that are at those locations? Or a boolean indicating whether any results exist?

Comment: I am trying to get a list of cars at those locations not a boolean sorry for being unclear

Comment: See Ivan's answer. I was scratching up something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if I do have an array of locations I would like to determine if a column from a joined table/model **is equal** to **any** of the strings in the locations array.

You can use `locations` [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118(v=vs.110).aspx) method for that.

Also you can simplify the query by putting the `dealers` into variable, optionally applying the filter and then use it inside the query like this:

```
using (dbContext db = new dbContext())
{
    var dealers = db.Dealers.AsQueryable();
    if (locations != null)
        dealers = dealers.Where(dealer => locations.Contains(dealer.LocationName));

    var query = (from car in db.Cars
                 join dealer in dealers on car.DealerID equals dealer.DealerNumber
                 select new
                 {
                     ID = car.VinNumber,
                     make = car.Make,
                     model = car.Model,
                     Dealer = dealer.DealerName
                  });

    return Ok(query.ToList());
}
```

P.S. If you actually need a partial match as in your original code, then you can use [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead:

```
    if (locations != null)
        dealers = dealers.Where(dealer => locations.Any(location => dealer.LocationName.Contains(location)));
```